# Could not find aws-eventstream-1.1.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, bundle, githooks

I have four error messages mentioned below:

1. Could not find aws-eventstream-1.1.0 in any of the sources
2. Failed to install gems via Bundler
3. Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
4. [remote rejected] user-microposts -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

I think number one is the cause of the latter. But I can't find any proper information about how to get the gem aws-eventstream-1.1.0 in "the sources". I just follow the Ruby-on-Rails course of Michael Hartl.
Michael Hartl thinks it has to do with the AWS configuration.
So it would be very convenient if there a way to check wether the configuration is good before deploying. Does this exist?

Since I will only use this AWS-account for the sake of this course I will share the configuration data:

cli:

```
➜  sample_app git:(following-users)$ heroku config:set \
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAXOOFOGFFI62ZSAJR \
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=WI2ez9rn16SgqmKFcV9CsUt9hqLkpf49iktsKpa+ \
        AWS_REGION=eu-central-1 \
        AWS_BUCKET=rails-tutorial-josufst-1
```

storage.yml

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id:     <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
  region:            <%= ENV['AWS_REGION'] %>
  bucket:            <%= ENV['AWS_BUCKET'] %>
```

Below I posted the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock and the .gitignore.

The aws-eventstream-1.1.0 seems to be present in the Gemfile.lock.

I tried to do:

```
bundle install
bundle update
git add -A
git commit -m "whatever I tried"
git push heroku user-microposts:master
```

Also I run the app locally and run all tests locally. Everything works fine.
As far as I know I followed all the steps in the Ruby on Rails Tutorial.

And now I tried the `git push -f heroku user-microposts:master` (force) to see if it has something to do with the "hook". Although, as a newbie I don't understand the concept of hook.

```
➜  sample_app git:(user-microposts) git push -f heroku user-microposts:master
Enumerating objects: 1525, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1525/1525), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1307/1307), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1394/1394), 4.90 MiB | 65.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1394 (delta 310), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.0.2
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.6.3
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.0.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
remote:        Could not find aws-eventstream-1.1.0 in any of the sources
remote:        Bundler Output: Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
remote:        Could not find aws-eventstream-1.1.0 in any of the sources
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to rails-tutorial-josufst.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/rails-tutorial-josufst.git
 ! [remote rejected] user-microposts -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/rails-tutorial-josufst.git'
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

gem 'rails',                      '6.0.3.2'
gem 'image_processing',           '1.9.3'
gem 'mini_magick',                '4.9.5'
gem 'active_storage_validations', '0.8.9'
gem 'bcrypt',                     '3.1.13'
gem 'faker',                      '2.11.0'
gem 'will_paginate',              '3.3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate',    '1.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',             '3.4.1'
gem 'puma',                       '4.3.5'
gem 'sass-rails',                 '6.0.0'
gem 'webpacker',                  '4.2.2'
gem 'turbolinks',                 '5.2.1'
gem 'jbuilder',                   '2.10.0'
gem 'bootsnap',                   '1.4.6', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.4.2'
  gem 'byebug',  '11.1.3', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '4.0.2'
  gem 'listen',                '3.2.1'
  gem 'spring',                '2.1.0'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara',                 '3.32.2'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver',       '3.142.7'
  gem 'webdrivers',               '4.3.0'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.4'
  gem 'minitest',                 '5.11.3'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.3.8'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.16.2'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.6'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',         '1.2.3'
  gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '1.46.0', require: false
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
# Uncomment the following line if you're running Rails
# on a native Windows system:
# gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.0.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.2)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.0.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.2)
      activejob (= 6.0.3.2)
      activerecord (= 6.0.3.2)
      activestorage (= 6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.0.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.2)
      actionview (= 6.0.3.2)
      activejob (= 6.0.3.2)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.0.3.2)
      actionview (= 6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.8)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.0.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.2)
      activerecord (= 6.0.3.2)
      activestorage (= 6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    active_storage_validations (0.8.9)
      rails (>= 5.2.0)
    activejob (6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
    activerecord (6.0.3.2)
      activemodel (= 6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
    activestorage (6.0.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.2)
      activejob (= 6.0.3.2)
      activerecord (= 6.0.3.2)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (6.0.3.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    ansi (1.5.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (9.8.6.3)
      execjs
    aws-eventstream (1.1.0)
    aws-partitions (1.364.0)
    aws-sdk-core (3.105.0)
      aws-eventstream (~> 1, >= 1.0.2)
      aws-partitions (~> 1, >= 1.239.0)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
      jmespath (~> 1.0)
    aws-sdk-kms (1.37.0)
      aws-sdk-core (~> 3, >= 3.99.0)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
    aws-sdk-s3 (1.46.0)
      aws-sdk-core (~> 3, >= 3.61.1)
      aws-sdk-kms (~> 1)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
    aws-sigv4 (1.2.2)
      aws-eventstream (~> 1, >= 1.0.2)
    bcrypt (3.1.13)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.4.6)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    bootstrap-sass (3.4.1)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1)
      sassc (>= 2.0.0)
    bootstrap-will_paginate (1.0.0)
      will_paginate
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    capybara (3.32.2)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (~> 1.5)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    coderay (1.1.3)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.7)
    crass (1.0.6)
    erubi (1.9.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    faker (2.11.0)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
    ffi (1.13.1)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    guard (2.16.2)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      lumberjack (>= 1.0.12, < 2.0)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      notiffany (~> 0.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-compat (1.2.1)
    guard-minitest (2.4.6)
      guard-compat (~> 1.2)
      minitest (>= 3.0)
    i18n (1.8.5)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    image_processing (1.9.3)
      mini_magick (>= 4.9.5, < 5)
      ruby-vips (>= 2.0.13, < 3)
    jbuilder (2.10.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    jmespath (1.4.0)
    listen (3.2.1)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    loofah (2.7.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    lumberjack (1.2.8)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mimemagic (0.3.5)
    mini_magick (4.9.5)
    mini_mime (1.0.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    minitest-reporters (1.3.8)
      ansi
      builder
      minitest (>= 5.0)
      ruby-progressbar
    msgpack (1.3.3)
    nenv (0.3.0)
    nio4r (2.5.2)
    nokogiri (1.10.10)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    notiffany (0.1.3)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
    pg (1.2.3)
    pry (0.13.1)
      coderay (~> 1.1)
      method_source (~> 1.0)
    public_suffix (4.0.6)
    puma (4.3.5)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    rack (2.2.3)
    rack-proxy (0.6.5)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (6.0.3.2)
      actioncable (= 6.0.3.2)
      actionmailbox (= 6.0.3.2)
      actionmailer (= 6.0.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.2)
      actiontext (= 6.0.3.2)
      actionview (= 6.0.3.2)
      activejob (= 6.0.3.2)
      activemodel (= 6.0.3.2)
      activerecord (= 6.0.3.2)
      activestorage (= 6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 6.0.3.2)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-controller-testing (1.0.4)
      actionpack (>= 5.0.1.x)
      actionview (>= 5.0.1.x)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.1.x)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (6.0.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.20.3, < 2.0)
    rake (13.0.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.4)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    regexp_parser (1.7.1)
    ruby-progressbar (1.10.1)
    ruby-vips (2.0.17)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    rubyzip (2.3.0)
    sass-rails (6.0.0)
      sassc-rails (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
    sassc (2.4.0)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    shellany (0.0.1)
    spring (2.1.0)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (4.0.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.4.2)
    thor (1.0.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.7)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    web-console (4.0.2)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (4.3.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 3.0, < 4.0)
    webpacker (4.2.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 4.2)
    websocket-driver (0.7.3)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    will_paginate (3.3.0)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.4.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  active_storage_validations (= 0.8.9)
  aws-sdk-s3 (= 1.46.0)
  bcrypt (= 3.1.13)
  bootsnap (= 1.4.6)
  bootstrap-sass (= 3.4.1)
  bootstrap-will_paginate (= 1.0.0)
  byebug (= 11.1.3)
  capybara (= 3.32.2)
  faker (= 2.11.0)
  guard (= 2.16.2)
  guard-minitest (= 2.4.6)
  image_processing (= 1.9.3)
  jbuilder (= 2.10.0)
  listen (= 3.2.1)
  mini_magick (= 4.9.5)
  minitest (= 5.11.3)
  minitest-reporters (= 1.3.8)
  pg (= 1.2.3)
  puma (= 4.3.5)
  rails (= 6.0.3.2)
  rails-controller-testing (= 1.0.4)
  sass-rails (= 6.0.0)
  selenium-webdriver (= 3.142.7)
  spring (= 2.1.0)
  spring-watcher-listen (= 2.0.1)
  sqlite3 (= 1.4.2)
  turbolinks (= 5.2.1)
  web-console (= 4.0.2)
  webdrivers (= 4.3.0)
  webpacker (= 4.2.2)
  will_paginate (= 3.3.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   2.1.4
```

.gitignore

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files for more about ignoring files.
#
# If you find yourself ignoring temporary files generated by your text editor
# or operating system, you probably want to add a global ignore instead:
#   git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore_global'

# Ignore bundler config.
/.bundle

# Ignore the default SQLite database.
/db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal
/db/*.sqlite3-*

# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*
/tmp/*
!/log/.keep
!/tmp/.keep

# Ignore pidfiles, but keep the directory.
/tmp/pids/*
!/tmp/pids/
!/tmp/pids/.keep

# Ignore uploaded files in development.
/storage/*
!/storage/.keep

/public/assets
.byebug_history

# Ignore master key for decrypting credentials and more.
/config/master.key

/public/packs
/public/packs-test
/node_modules
/yarn-error.log
yarn-debug.log*
.yarn-integrity

# Ignore vendor/bundle
/vendor/bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say, it's the first error which is causing the other error reports you've read. So we should focus on that. Specifically, we will focus on this part.

```
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.0.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
remote:        Could not find aws-eventstream-1.1.0 in any of the sources
remote:        Bundler Output: Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
remote:        Could not find aws-eventstream-1.1.0 in any of the sources
```

This snippet is Bundler running on Heroku and failing.

It is good debugging practice when working with containers (that's what Heroku runs your app on, a container. A container is a virtual computer within a computer) to first get the failing *thing* to run locally on your native machine first (whatever you've been developing on).  It is good debugging practice to this because it simplifies what could go wrong and, typically, if you can get it to work locally on your native machine then it'll work in the container.

So, we're running a test. We need to make sure our test is the same as what occurs in the container. Luckily Bundler is a babe and it's told us what command it's running:

```
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
```

So we need to get that command to run locally on your machine.

It is time to step through each component of this `bundle install` command and spend the time to learn what it is doing. Or it would be in most cases, as that's the unfortunate truth to debugging; it usually takes patient slow methodical work.

But, I suspect I know the answer here. Notice the `--deployment` flag option in the command above. That [puts Bundler in deployment mode](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-install.1.html#DEPLOYMENT-MODE), which gears it up for Production usage (it's default is for development usage). One of the things that does is tells Bundler to not download gems from rubygems.org (the default) but, instead grab them from the local directory `vendor/cache/`.

I suspect that you've, in your git branch, got a `vendor/cache/` directory but it doesn't contain all the gems Bundle expects. Hence these complaints from Bundler.

```
remote:        Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
remote:        Could not find aws-eventstream-1.1.0 in any of the sources
remote:        Bundler Output: Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
remote:        Could not find aws-eventstream-1.1.0 in any of the sources
```

One option would be to remove the `--deployment` flag but, my guess is that's not an option because Heroku controls what command is used and we can't change it. I've not any experience with Heroku but, if my better idea doesn't work we can come back and explore this option.

So! I need some information from you please. Can you share your `.gitignore` file please?

Comment: I added the .gitignore file.